# Combining multiple images and text using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am new to ImageMagick and I am trying to add 3 different labels to 3 different (small) images, and then insert them over a background image, each being in a corner.

All of the images, and text strings are unknown before-hand and that's why I'm writing a script to handle this. My latest (failed) attempt is:

```
convert -page +0+0 ${bg}.png \
    \( -page +0+0 -gravity south  -pointsize 16 \
    -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 4 -annotate 0 "$label" \
    -stroke  none   -strokewidth 20 -fill white    -annotate 0 "$label" \) \
    \( -page +0+0 ${im1}.png \
    -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 "text1" \
    -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 "text1" \) \
    \( -page +${hor_offset}+0 {im2}.png \
    -gravity south  -pointsize 14 \
    -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 "text2" \
    -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 "text2" \) \
    \( -page +0+${ver_offset} ${im3}.png \
    -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 "text3" \
    -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 "text3" \) \
    +page -flatten out.png
```

I have had a better result earlier, but it was mainly by chance and decided to seek an expert's help.

The final result should look something like this: [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxyXo.png)

Answer (score 0):

-page does not respect -gravity. -page is always relative to the northwest corner (top-left) of the image. You can alternately, use -gravity and -geometry with -composite in pairs. Create one image, then composite over the background in the correct location. The repeat with that result and another image to overlay. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert